# Use cloud function, or chain together Firebase writes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Let's say there are 2 Firebase writes that go together, such as "liking a post" and "adding my uid to the list of people that liked the post."

Is it better to chain together the actions in my client code (adding the second write in the completion block of the first)?

Or is it better to use a cloud function that does the second write that is triggered on the first?

I'm asking on a cost standpoint, and how susceptible to hacking is client code? Is it easy for the client to disallow the second write after the first, especially in web applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind using cloud functions in this case would be to take as much processing as possible out of your app, not only for cost and security but also to make it more efficient and fast.

The second option is definitely more secure, since the Cloud Function would be a event triggered function, making it "uninvocable" by the malicious users.

As per costs, for Firestore either options would represent 2 writes, but the second option would represent also a cost of Compute Time on your Cloud Function, you can get more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#compute_time). There is a free tier for Cloud Functions, but as you app scale this may become significant, so that's something to be considered.